# Angular2, NodeJS & Passport Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, passport.js

Currently my Angular2 front-end runs on `localhost:3000` and the NodeJS back-end (based on KrakenJS) runs on `localhost:8000`. When I put in the credentials I call the `this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/login', body, { headers: contentHeaders })` api, but I get the following response in Chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/login. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:8000/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

But when I call the `this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/register', body, { headers: contentHeaders })` it all works fine and does all the registration magic (hashing pswd, storing details in database..etc.).

Here is my simple register API from (register.js):

```
 router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        var User = require('../../models/user');

        User.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }).then(
            function() {
                res.render('user/registered', {registered: true});
            },
            function() {
                res.render('user/registered', {registered: false});
            }
        );
    } else {
        res.render('user/registered', {registered: false});
    }
});
```

Here is the Login api from (login.js):

```
 router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: req.session.goingTo || '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable CORS in your main server file with:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: `*` should not be your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value. It defeats the purpose of the browsers security features.